# cloudfront video streaming not working on ios devices

Tags: ios, amazon-s3, xcode6, video-streaming, amazon-cloudfront

I am trying to stream the video on IOS devices using amazon cloudfront web distribution(RTMP streaming is not supported by apple devices) and video is stored in s3 .Moreover the link is accessible to everyone.When I try to paste the video link in browser the video starts to download instead of streaming.
After inspecting on instagram's websites I came to know that instagram does the same thing(maybe) but the difference is it uses akamai CDN and I am using amazon's cloudfront

My link:

```
http://d16jy53srxox6v.cloudfront.net/brown.mp4
```

Instagram video streaming link:

```
https://igcdn-videos-b-2-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xfa1/t50.2886-16/11773361_692383954227382_242786346_n.mp4
```

Where instagram video streams perfectly and my video gets download rather than streaming.After hitting google I found HLS is one of the solution yet I am looking for easy streaming alternative as my video max length would be 1 minute and HLS is good for larger files.Can anyone suggest me what should I do to make my video streamable without HLS?

Morover I tried to stream it in ios device but it tries to download and then plays it.Heres my code:

```
    -(IBAction)click:(id)sender
{
    // Make a URL
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:
                  @"http://d16jy53srxox6v.cloudfront.net/brown.mp4"];

    // Initialize the MPMoviePlayerController object using url
    _videoPlayer =  [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]
                     initWithContentURL:url];


    // Set control style to default
    _videoPlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleDefault;

    // Set shouldAutoplay to YES
    _videoPlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES;
    _videoPlayer.movieSourceType=MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming;

    // Add _videoPlayer's view as subview to current view.
    [self.view addSubview:_videoPlayer.view];

    // Set the screen to full.
    [_videoPlayer setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: did you find a solution to this? I am trying the same, but when I try to play m3u8 file, it starts playing only after downloading the whole file.

Comment: I have not found any solution yet

Answer (score -1):

Problem Might be the `content type` of the uploaded video

You can go to the s3 bucket and check the `metadata` field under `properties` tab

I faced the same issue with one of my videos on s3 it used to get downloaded instead of playing it.

I resolved this issue by adding metadata to the video as
`Content-Type = video/mp4`

hope this helps

Comment: without using HLS if I check the metadata and setting the content type = video/mp4. and after getting the url from CloudFront will start buffering on the avplayer ?